# Hardware and System clock both wrong in linux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, timezone, clock

I dual booted my laptop and installed EndeavourOS (while other OS being windows 10)

Due to this, my hardware and system clock both show the wrong time.

I have set the correct time zone (UTC+5:30), still it shows the wrong time.

[image]

`timedatctl`

```
 Local time: Sat 2023-02-25 09:12:46 IST

 Universal time: Sat 2023-02-25 03:42:46 UTC
 
 RTC time: Sat 2023-02-25 03:42:46
 
 Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
 
 System clock synchronized: no
          
 NTP service: active
      
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

This is the snap of my terminal which is showing the wrong time even the UTC time which is around 3:59 and the local time here is 9:29 at the moment of writing this post.

I have looked at various sites, but couldn't find a fix for this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Copy and paste it so that it's easier to access

Comment: When you do paste it as text, please identify not only what UTC is/was, but also what local time is/was at the same moment, and what timezone you're in.

Comment: @roaima I have now written the text as well.

Answer (score 2):

So your UTC time is about 17 minutes off.

```
System clock synchronized: no
NTP service: active
```

Although the NTP service is active, the `System clock synchronized: no` indicates it has not succeeded in getting accurate time information from the NTP servers it may be configured to contact.

You should look at the status and configuration of the actual NTP service. It might be literally `ntpd`, or `chronyd`, or `systemd-timesyncd`. (Note that `systemd-timesyncd` is a SNTP client, unlike the other two, which are both full-featured NTP clients.)

To query the status of `ntpd`, use `ntpq -np`.

If you have `chronyd` instead, use `chronyc -n sources`

For `systemd-timesyncd`, use `timedatectl show-timesync --all`.

The outputs of these commands should reveal if the NTP synchronization service is configured with any NTP servers, and if it has managed to contact any of them. I'd expect that you'll find that either no NTP servers are currently configured, or that the server has failed to reach them.

The configuration of `ntpd` is typically at `/etc/ntp.conf`, `chronyd`'s is at several files and sub-directories in `/etc/chrony/`, and `systemd-timesyncd` is configured at `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

Since your system clock is so far off the real time, the time synchronization servers might fail to sync it automatically, in order to avoid large time jumps. If so, you might have to start the synchronization manually once with an appropriate option to allow large time adjustments: for ntpd, it would be `ntpd -qg`.

Comment: The service is `ntpd`. Please have a look at [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jpDe.png) outputs after I followed your instructions. What do I do next?

Comment: The `reach` field in `ntpq -np` output is all zeroes, indicating that `ntpd` has not received responses from any of the four configured NTP servers. Your next task is to figure out why. Have you e.g. blocked incoming traffic to UDP port 123 (= the port used by NTP) with an `iptables` or `nftables` firewall?

Answer (score 1):

> Due to this, my hardware and system clock both show the wrong time.

Hmmm. That seems unlikely. However if the *other* OS was MS-Windows, that might explain some of the disparity. When PCs shipped with MS-DOS (or even DR-DOS) the hardware clock was set to local time / MS-DOS didn't understand timezones. The ghost of MS-DOS is still present in modern MS-Windows - which can be configured to keep the HW clock in sync with the local timezone or in UTC. However since your computer appears to only be out by 15 minutes, it would appear that your other OS was using UTC on the hw clock.

OTOH you have tagged this with "arch-linux" and say you installed EndeavourOS - so presumably both OS are running differnt versions of Linux. I presume that when you boot up in Arch Linux it shows the same discrepancy now.

Linux only reads the hw clock at boot or when it decides to sync the hw clock to the time it worked out itself. For these to be 15 minutes apart without being up for months is also rather unlikely.

The most likely cause is that your hw clock is simply wrong. You can set the system clock (then one Linux uses at runtime) using the `date` command or via ntp. Once this is done, you need to set the hw clock - which is done with the hwclock command.

You'll find descriptions of using the date and hwclock commands in the man pages on your local machine.

Comment: My other OS is indeed windows. I just tagged it with arch-linux because Endeavour is arch based.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to different time assumptions of Linux and MS Windows. By default, MS Windows assumes the time is stored in local time while Linux assumes the time is stored in UTC time. Consequently one of your operating systems will show wrong time when you are dual-booting.
The solution might be, either make Linux use local time; or make MS Windows use UTC. The second option is probably not easy and I am not aware how to change these things in that OS.
However, if you want to make Linux use local time, you can do that by this command:

`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock`

Thereafter if you run the command you have shown us `timedatectl`  you will see a slightly different output: `“RTC in local TZ: yes”`.

Comment: `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock` changes the local time and UTC time to entirely some other time, however it does change RTC in local TZ to yes.

Comment: I ran `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock` which displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAD9b.png) output, while the local time is around 9:58 and UTC time is 4:28 at this moment.